# Send Email with line breaks JSOM REST

Tags: rest, email, jsom

I want to send email with a body consisting of multiple lines. I am using REST Post requests.

I tried adding `"\n"`, adding `"\r\n"`, using `encodeURIComponent()` method as well. But neither works.

Is there any headers or anything that I want to use?

I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where the email is displayed. Most are Browser based so require a <BR>